# PHP 5: how to write utf-8 binary data - image - to output?

Tags: php, file, utf-8

I have a Ubuntu server and PHP5, and the PHP script files, and all output are in UTF-8.
I'm trying to send an image to the output stream, but just garbled chinese characters shows up in the output:

`$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);

$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);

imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

imagejpeg($im);

imagedestroy($im);`

any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to output textual data and that image in the same script? That’s not possible. Both the textual data and the image are different resources and thus must be different files.

Comment: no, just the image, nothing is written before / after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine on my machine :

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5, 'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);

die;
?>
```

Are you sure you are not outputing **anything** before or after that code ? Even any kind of whitespace would be a source of troubles.

Or maybe your script is doing something else somewhere ?

If it still doesn't work, maybe trying with [`imagettftext`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php), to use a "better" / more complete font than the ones used by `imagestring` might help ?

Using something like this, for instance :

```
$font = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arial.ttf';
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $text_color, $font, 'A Simple éléphant String');
```

BTW, did you try without those line :

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

If there is an error/warning/notice, removing those lines might help you seeing those.

And, as a sidenote : using JPEG for images that contain some text generally doesn't give great results, as JPEG is a destructive compression mechanism. Using PNG, in that kind of situation, might get you better results ;-)

Comment: possibly, but I haven't find anything yet. There are 16 included files... it's not my code, I just need to modify some stuff in it, sadly.

Comment: Ergh :-( not so nice ;; well, I suppose first thing would be to test the smallest part of code that you can, to determine if your server can generate the image outside of your application ;; then, removing the three lines that output the image might help getting error messages...

Comment: I've moved it to a standalone file.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the UTF-8 byte order mark, because it gets prepended to the contents of your JPEG image, rendering it invalid.

Comment: first of all that's true! However, after removing the first 3 bytes 'ď»ż' of a downloaded file, it's still an invalid image.