# My $_FILES['file']['name'] is producing gibberish

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I am uploading files with the following code using Bootstrap as my front-end framework.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action= "php/up-load.php" role="form"
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="file" class="col-sm-5 control-label">
      Select file(Compressed format)
    </label>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000000"/>
      <input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept=".zip, .rar"/> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>                                                           
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="upload" id="upload">Send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My php code is;

```
@ $original=$_FILES['file']['name'];
@ $kiss=pathinfo($original, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$allowed_extensions = array(".zip","rar","bzip2","iso","gz","rz","7z","tar","tgz","bz2","tbz2","lzma","tlz");

$result = in_array ("$kiss", $allowed_extensions);

if (!$result)
{
  // Wrong file type
}
else
{
  //proceed..
}
```

My problem is that the

```
$_FILES['file']['name'];
```

is returning gibberish such as `php7vy8X9` and `phpY8wQVR` . Have tried everything. What could be the problem?

Comment: It's temporary file-name given by php. What you expecting ?

Comment: Do you mean `name` or `tmp_name`?

Comment: $_FILES['file']['name'] This will return you the file name. These kind of names may be in tmp_name. for more please check this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: you didn't close: <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="php/up-load.php" role="form"> and maybe you can take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236035/insert-picture-into-database-using-php/22236798#22236798

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES["file"]["name"]` should be returning the original name of your file, what you are reporting should be stored inside `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`

The whole `$_FILES` array should look like this:

```
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"]; // Original Name
echo $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; // Name (and location) given to the file by PHP
echo $_FILES["file"]["type"]; // File/mime type
echo $_FILES["file"]["size"]; // Total bytes
echo $_FILES["file"]["error"]; // Any error code which is returned during transfer
```