# PHP: After uploading a picture it won't load and there's a loophole

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Filmovi</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="unos.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table border = "1">
    <tr>
    <td>Naslov:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="naslov" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Žanr:</td>
    <td>
    <?php

    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'kolekcija');
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT id, naziv FROM zanr");

    echo "<select name = 'id'>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        unset($id, $name);
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['naziv'];
        echo '<option value = "' . $id . '">'.$name.'</option>';
    }

    echo "</select>";

    ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Godina:</td>
    <td>
    <select name = "godina">
    <?php

    for($i = 1900; $i <= 2020; $i++)
    {
        echo "<option value = " .$i . ">" .$i . "</option>";
    }

    ?>
    <option name = "godina"></option>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Trajanje:</td>
    <td><input type="integer" name="trajanje" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Slika:</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type = "hidden" name = "size" value = "1000000000" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Gumb:</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Unos" /></td>
    </tr>

        </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>

<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die 
(mysqli_connect_errno());
mysqli_select_db($link, "kolekcija") or die ("Nemoguće se spojiti na 
bazu!".mysqli_connect_errno());

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $filepath = "/unos.php:116".$filename;
    $naslov=$_POST['naslov'];
    $trajanje = $_POST['trajanje'];
    $zanr = $_POST['id'];
    $godina = $_POST['godina'];
    move_uploaded_file($filename, $filepath);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO filmovi (id, naziv_filma, trajanje, slika, 
id_zanr, godina)
                VALUES('null', '{$naslov}', '{$trajanje}' ,'{$filepath}', 
'{$zanr}', '{$godina}');";
     $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die("Error in Query insert: " . 
mysqli_connect_errno());

    }

$msg = "";

$sql = "SELECT id, slika, naziv_filma, godina, trajanje FROM filmovi";
$myData = mysqli_query($link, $sql); 
echo "<table border = '1'>
<tr>
<th>Slika</th><th>Naziv filma</th><th>Godina</th><th>Trajanje</th>
<th>Akcija</th></tr>";
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($myData)) 
    {
    echo "<form action = 'unos.php' method = 'post' enctype='multipart/form-
data'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $msg.= '<img 
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($record['slika']) .'"/>' . "
</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['naziv_filma'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['godina'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['trajanje'] . "</td>";
    echo '<td>[<a href="unos.php?film='.$record[0].'">obriši</a>]</td>';

    if(isset($_GET['film']))
    {
        $id = ($_GET['film']);

        $sql_delete = "DELETE FROM filmovi WHERE id = {$id}";

        mysqli_query($link, $sql_delete);

        break;
    }


    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
    }




echo "</table>";

?>
```

Okay, this is my code, I have a programming course and this was the 
assigment. The idea was to make a form where you can put info about the movie, name, genre, year it was made and upload a picture. Everythign works and it's done but the only problem is that after uploading a picture (directly in the mysql database, I don't have a code where the picture is stored at the local disk), it won't load in the browser and after refreshing the browser the picture uploads itself again. It seems I have a loop somwhere but I can't figure out where 'cause I've been doing it and delaying the code for months as I'm stuck. Can someone help, please? Thank you very much in advance for all help!

Comment: You have an great example on how to store a picture in DB with PHP covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236035/insert-picture-into-database-using-php

Comment: You have to specify the folder in which you would like to save your images, so change your `$filepath = "/unos.php:116".$filename;` into `$filepath = "/directory/".$filename;`. Of course bare in mind that you have to have correct permissions on that folder.